# v-data-table doesn't updates on a new data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a object `portfoliosData` in a Vuex store. This object has a property `metrics`

```
  state: {
    portfoliosData: {
      performance: [],
      metrics: []
    },
```

When performing an action I mutate the property in the store and want to show the updates in a table.

```
 <div id="amsample">
  <div id="chartdiv"></div>
   <v-tabs-items  :touchless="true">
      <v-tabs-content :key="0" id="tab-1">
        <v-card flat>
          <v-card-text>
            Return Performance
            <v-data-table
              :headers="headers"
              :items="metrics"
              :custom-sort="sortPercentage"
              hide-actions
              class="elevation-1"
            >
              <template slot="items" scope="props">
                <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
                <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.acRet }}</td>
                <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.anRet }}</td>
                <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.anVol }}</td>
                <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.maxDd }}</td>
                <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.sRatio }}</td>
                <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.inRatio }}</td>
              </template>
            </v-data-table>
          </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-tabs-content>
    </v-tabs-items>
 </div>
```

In the component table observes the metrics variable.

```
data() {
      return {

        headers: [
          {text: 'Measure', value: 'name', sortable: false},
          {text: 'Accumulative Return', value: 'acRet'},
          {text: 'Annual Return', value: 'anRet'},
          {text: 'Annual Volatility', value: 'anVol'},
          {text: 'Max Drawdown', value: 'maxDd'},
          {text: 'Sharpe Ratio', value: 'sRatio'},
          {text: 'Information Ratio', value: 'inRatio'},
        ],
        metrics: []
      }
    },
```

When I call an action in the component I get the updated `metrics` from the store

```
//Component
  calulateMetrics(event) {
    this.$store.dispatch('performeMetricsCalculation', {dataZoomStart:event.startDate, dataZoomEnd:event.endDate}).then(() => {
      this.metrics = this.$store.getters.getMetrics;
      console.log("Calculated metric", this.metrics)
    })
  },

//actions
performeMetricsCalculation({dispatch, commit, getters}, {dataZoomStart, dataZoomEnd}) {
  //console.log("performeMetricsCalculation", dataZoomStart, dataZoomEnd)

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dispatch('performSetRangeTime', {dataZoomStart: dataZoomStart, dataZoomEnd: dataZoomEnd}).then(() => {
      dispatch('performMetrcisUpdating').then(() => {
        commit('resetUpdateStatus')
      })
    })
    resolve()
  })
},

performMetrcisUpdating({commit}) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    commit('calculateMetrics')
    resolve()
  })
},
```

During debugging I printed the `metrics` variable and I see that the data differers from the initial one. But the table doesn't updates.

In `mutations` I use the following logic

```
calculateMetrics({portfoliosData, period, status}) {
  let updatedMetrics = []

  for (let s in portfoliosData.performance) {
    if (portfoliosData.performance.hasOwnProperty(s)) {
      //console.log("Calculate metrics", period.startDateIdx, period.endDateIdx)
      let port = {...portfoliosData.performance[s]}

      updatedMetrics.push({
        name: port.name,
        maxDd: maxDrawdown(port.data, period.startDateIdx, period.endDateIdx),
        acRet: accumulativeReturn(port.data, period.startDateIdx, period.endDateIdx),
        anRet: annualReturn(port.data, period.startDateIdx, period.endDateIdx),
        anVol: annualVolatility(port.data, period.startDateIdx, period.endDateIdx),
        sRatio: sharpeRatio(port.data, period.startDateIdx, period.endDateIdx),
        inRatio: informationRatio(port.data, period.startDateIdx, period.endDateIdx)
      })

      if (!status.isUpdated) {
        portfoliosData.metrics = updatedMetrics
      } else {
        Vue.set(portfoliosData, 'metrics', updatedMetrics)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I get the data without performing an action there is no problem with updating the table. However when I want to update the table the new data doesn't render, although the `metrics` variable changes. That looks weird.

I observe this issue only in this specific case. Also I tried to change `:items="metrics"` to `:items=$store.getters.getMetrics` but it didn't help me either.

Comment: You mention dispatching to `performeMetricsCalculation`, but your mutation is named `calculateMetrics` with different parameters than what you had dispatched. Are these typos? If not, please show the definition of `performeMetricsCalculation` and how the `calculateMetrics` mutation is related. Also, it would be helpful to provide a codepen/codesandbox to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @tony19 no, it is not a typo, I edited my question and add two action method that call `calculateMetrics` mutation

Comment: @tony19 I tried to reproduce the error with artificial data but failed. It works fine. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/9jz98r2x3o
But I guess there should not a problem on API part

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change `mutations` to

```
calculateMetrics(state) {
  let {portfoliosData, period, status} = state // ES6 syntax
  let updatedMetrics = []

  for (let s in portfoliosData.performance) {
    if (portfoliosData.performance.hasOwnProperty(s)) {
      //console.log("Calculate metrics", period.startDateIdx, period.endDateIdx)
      let port = {...portfoliosData.performance[s]}

      updatedMetrics.push({
        name: port.name,
        maxDd: maxDrawdown(port.data, period.startDateIdx, period.endDateIdx),
        acRet: accumulativeReturn(port.data, period.startDateIdx, period.endDateIdx),
        anRet: annualReturn(port.data, period.startDateIdx, period.endDateIdx),
        anVol: annualVolatility(port.data, period.startDateIdx, period.endDateIdx),
        sRatio: sharpeRatio(port.data, period.startDateIdx, period.endDateIdx),
        inRatio: informationRatio(port.data, period.startDateIdx, period.endDateIdx)
      })


    }
  }
   portfoliosData.metrics = updatedMetrics
   state.portfoliosData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(portfoliosData)) // assign to new object
}
```

We need to create new object (I used JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) technique) to make `vuex` understand data is changed.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I'll check you solution a bit later, but from the first glance I can't understand the benefits. Vuex updates my data (I logged the state after mutation). Also according to docs (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats) for updating is recommended to use `Vue.set` method. Why do you think that dividing logic for creating property and updating is a bad idea.

Comment: These caveat is using in Vue component, not vuex store. Please try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: I tried but the problem remains. It is still updates the state but the table doesn't react to this updates.